# Azure Function Transforms During VSTS Build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to apply something similar to a [VSTS File Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts) to an Azure Function during the VSTS build process?

I have an Azure Function App with one function per deployment environment (dev, test, prod). These functions are nearly identical except for the following values that need to be updated per each specific deployment:

1. Function name
2. Integrated service bus queue name
3. TraceWriter prefix for logging

Code outline for these values, note the "Dev" prefixes:

```
public static class DevFunction {
    [FunctionName("DevFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(...)] HttpRequestMessage request,
        [ServiceBus("devQueueName", ...] ICollector<string> outputBus,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("Starting DevFunction");
        ... // Do work
    }
}
```

I want to consolidate these functions into a single function and use something similar to a VSTS File Transform to update the above listed information during my build process for a given deployment. I currently have three separate VS projects, each with it's own function to be deployed to each individual environment. Are there better options here?

Comment: How about just using application settings?

Comment: Is there a way to transform a function using application settings?

Comment: You can configure e.g. queue name or prefix, and then deploy under a name

Comment: To clarify, you are referring to the Function App Application Settings, right? If I define an app setting for e.g. queue name, how do I actually change the value of that setting in a VSTS build step? Function Apps don't have a web.config.

Comment: You can use ARM Template Task or a powershell script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure Functions don't support a standard config/settings transformation. There are, however, a variety of workarounds for transforming a function per deployment environment:

#### 0. Future Solution

Ideally, Azure will add support for a standard web.config equivalent for functions. From this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1594):

> [Jun 19, 2017] ...there is no good equivalent of a web.config file today for functions.
>   We plan on addressing this as part of our porting work to .NET core.

#### 1. Preprocessor Directives

For my scenario, using [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) ended up being the simplest solution. Each build configuration corresponds to a deployment. For example:

```
#if RELEASE
        [FunctionName("ReleaseFunction")]
#elif AZURETEST
        [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
#else
        [FunctionName("DevFunction")]
#endif
```

The build configuration is specified in the "Build Solution" step of each of my VSTS builds. Obviously, this code is rather ugly and could be hard to maintain depending on the number of transformations needed.

#### 2. Read a Custom Settings File

Also from the same [GitHub thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1594), a custom settings file can be created at the root of the function app and then read as needed:

```
var settingsPath = Path.Combine(executionContext.FunctionAppDirectory, "settings.json");
dynamic settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(settingsPath));
var myConfigValue = (string)settings.Values.MyConfigValue;
```

Note that this does not work for transforming the `FunctionName` and that [runtime bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime) may be needed to transform input/output bindings (such as the ServiceBus binding in the original question).

#### 3. PowerShell Text Replacement

Write a PowerShell script that performs a raw text transformation on the function file. Add a VSTS build step that runs the script before the solution is built. Any values needed for the transformation could be defined in the Function App's global Application Settings.

#### 4. ARM Template

Again from the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1594), it may be possible to use an ARM template to accomplish this.

> [Aug 10, 2017] My CI/CD setups use ARM templates to deploy the function apps with the
>   appropriate app settings. These ARM templates are in source control
>   and have CD hooked up so when I need to add a new app setting I just
>   commit the changes to the ARM template.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the built-in task can do it, but there are some extensions can update JSON files, such as [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens), [Tokenizer](https://github.com/colindembovsky/cols-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Tokenizer), you also can do it programming (e.g. PowerShell)